# Speech Services Javascript SDK slowness in response

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

we are using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstart-js-browser
 for filing user data on screen based on Voice input (`recognizeOnceAsync`)..but i am facing multiple problems in that

1. There is no way around to stop recognizer immediately once  i speak some words ..it take 4-5 seconds to stop mic processing ..
2. Assume that I want to enter user first name based on voice, but it takes 5-6 to complete the process ,which is not recommendable..need to your inputs to improve it.
3. Any results returned from Speech service is appended with extra (.)  in last of result. not sure why its happening.

We are in process of completing  POC for automated application Form fill application.